# Grid and Canvas inside a ScrollViewer element, Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, grid, scrollviewer

I have trouble understanding why is it that both canvas and grid's cannot be resized using RenderTransform if they are placed within a scrollviewer? If taken out of the scrollviewer, the grid or canvas resizes just fine but obviously it no longer is scrollable.

XAML code

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0"
                  x:Name="scrollWindow">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                x:Name="primaryGrid"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

C# code

```
public class MyClass
{
    private TranslateTransform move = new TranslateTransform();
    private ScaleTransform resize = new ScaleTransform();
    private TransformGroup transform= new TransformGroup();

    public MyClass(Grid primaryGrid, ScrollViewer scrollWindow)
    {
        transform.Children.Add(move);
        transform.Children.Add(resize);

        scrollWindow.ManipulationDelta += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(testManipulationDelta);
        scrollWindow.ManipulationMode = ManipulationMode.System;

        primaryGrid.RenderTransform = transform;
    }

    void testManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X > 0 && e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y > 0)
        {
            resize.ScaleX *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
            resize.ScaleY *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done, rather than just describe it please.

Comment: what about re sizing scroll view along with grid/canvas?